# When we do rm -rf * why we do not delete . and ..?

Tags: linux, rm

I am just curious. Is there a save guard there? . and .. is a "subdirectory" of the directory we are deleting right?

I know it's not a subdirectory but linux treat it as a file with directory property.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is not a part of `rm`, but a part of your shell. `*` is a glob which your shell expands and passes to `rm` in the form of arguments (`rm` never sees a literal `*`, unless the glob didn't match anything, in which case a literal `*` is passed). Standard `*` globs do not expand to include filenames beginning with a dot, which includes `.` and `..`. For example:

```
$ tee foo bar baz .foo .bar .baz < /dev/null
$ echo *
bar baz foo
$ echo .*
. .. .bar .baz .foo
```

Comment: In bash, `shopt -s dotglob` will cause dotfiles to be matched. Other shells probably have similar features.